# connecting to tibco and see the message body from the queue

Tags: jms, tibco

I am working in an application in which we use to send some messages in tibco queue, we are sending messages through spring jms and we have been provided by a customized interface in which graphically we can see the message count and can see that if that number increases then messages are being send on that queue, but i was looking for some tool which have GUI in which I can connect to my tibco queue and can see the message body also that is the message content in detail , please advise for such free tools , I think similar to queuezee tool.

This one is paid one http://jmsbrowser.com/...looking for free one

Comment: By TIBCO queue, do you mean TIBCO Enterprise Message Service (EMS) ?

Answer (score 3):

You could try GEMS(Graphical Administration Tool for EMS). Its a GUI tool built specifically to monitor the queues and topics in TIBCO EMS 
[TIBCO Community:GEMS tool](https://www.tibcommunity.com/docs/DOC-1154)

Also there is one more tool called Hermes which offers the almost the same functionality as GEMS

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveMQ,it is from Apache and its free.
You can see the messages sent and messages recieved.
Both queue and topic message counts can also be viewed